# Использование final аргумента в локальном классе

Tags: java, final

Без всяких лишних слов напишу код:

```
public class A {

    static Object f() {
        String str = "hello";
        str = "world";     //   (1) ошибка компиляции!

        class X extends Object {
            public String toString() {
                return str;
            }
        }

        return new X();
    }

    static Object g() {
        String[] s = { "hello", "silence" };
        s[0] = "World";      //   (2) НЕТ ошибки компиляции.

        class X extends Object{
            public String toString() {
                return s[0];
            }
        }

        return new X();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

}
```

Закомментирование строки `(1)` даст компилятору понять, что `str` в `f()` есть effectively final, код скомпилируется.
Закомментирование строки `(2)` не нужно. Ведь `s` -- ссылка на массив, которая не изменяется. Взятие `s[0]` затем законно.

**Вопрос:** Зачем от нас требую использование только final или effectively final локальных переменных в локальном классе? Я могу работать с первой ячейкой массива `s` и всё у меня будет замечательно.

---

Мои мысли и непонятки: как вообще будет выглядеть код объекта класса `f().X` ? Это будет объект с кодом из `Object`, но его метод `toString()` будет таким (псевдокод):

```
public String toString() {
    return 0x47e9c2dd;
}
```

Где, как понимаю, `0x47e9c2dd` адрес той самой строки `str`? Но если бы оно работало так, то какая разница какой адрес мы бы положили в этот метод, когда создавали экземпляр класса `f().X` ...

---

Так же не понимаю: мы определяем метод `toString()` класса `f().X` ссылаясь на локальную переменную str, которая (как ссылка) исчезнет по завершению работы `f()`, но при том объект возвращённый из `f()` содержит в своём `toString()` ссылку на `str` (как объект). Значит у нас тратится RAM на то, чтобы держать метод `f().X.toString()` определённым?....

---

В общем я очень запутался, совершенно не понимаю происходящего с этими локальными классами в том свете, что на нас возложено это странное требование на final или effectively final. Объясните происходящее, пожалуйста...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java замыкания захватывают значения, а не переменные. При компиляции внутреннего класса, Java создаст в нём поле для хранения значения переменной, "захваченной" из внешней области видимости:

```
$ javac A.java
$ javap A$1X

Compiled from "A.java"
class A$1X {
  final java.lang.String val$str; // <-- "hello"
  A$1X();
  public java.lang.String toString();
}
```

У требования к неизменяемости обеих переменных есть несколько причин.

Уверен, самым главным было то, что Java позиционируется как язык, в корне пресекающий возможность совершения множества ошибок и вынуждающий программистов писать правильный код. А классические замыкания - это не самая простая и интуитивно понятная тема. Поэтому в Java замыкания сознательно ограничили и сделали более простыми.

Кроме того, если реализовывать классические замыкания, то необходимо было бы каким-то образом сохранять захваченную переменную. Например, выделять место в куче. Во-первых, это потребовало бы доработки виртуальной машины и, возможно, изменения байт-кода. Во-вторых, это повод для утечек памяти.

Можно было бы сделать поле `val$str` изменяемым, но это усложнило бы и замедлило использование анонимных классов и лямбда-выражений в многопоточной среде. Можно было бы дать программисту возможность выбирать, когда это поле финальное, а когда нет, но тогда оно перестаёт быть неявным и мы опять приходит к необходимости доработки виртуальной машины, усложнению языка и поводам для ошибок.

Можно было бы не ограничивать изменяемость переменной из внешней области видимости, но на уровне языка переменная `str` одна, вероятность того, что в разных областях видимости она может иметь разные значения - это ещё больший повод для ошибок, чем классические замыкания.

Подытоживая, ограничение на неизменяемость переменных одновременно сделало и язык лучше, и техническую реализацию замыканий проще.

Кое-что об этом можно почитать у Брайана Гетца в "[State of the Lambda: Variable capture](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html)".

Comment: Думаю сейчас задам хороший дополнительный вопрос, ответив на который, пожалуйста(!), Вы поможете многим: говорится: «Кроме того, если реализовывать классические замыкания, то необходимо было бы каким-то образом сохранять захваченную переменную. Например, выделять место в куче.» Вопрос: а разве место для финальной ссылки val$str при создании экземпляра A$1X не выделяется? То есть, когда вызывается метод toString() этого самого экземпляра, у нас нет значения ссылки val$str? Т.е. чтобы узнать на что ссылается эта ссылка, JVM открывает метод A.f() и берёт от туда значение?...

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что трюк со скрытым полем позволил добавить в Java замыкания всего лишь небольшой модификацией компилятора, не изменяя ничего в виртуальной машине, не добавляя новых механизмов. В [V8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_V8), например, для сохранения замыканий создаётся специальный объект контекста, а в [СPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) стековый кадр сохраняется в куче до тех пор, пока существует замыкание.